# Can we install SSIS engine without BIDS etc? If yes would it be good idea to do it on production machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids, dtexec

I have brand new Windows machine which we are planning to use as production machine to run our SSIS packages. My pacakges are on filesystem not in SQL Server. Is it possible we can install SSIS Engine only without BIDS. Will utility like dtexec work if We install only SSIS Engine? Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Production` you wont be developing the SSIS packages so you don't need BIDS  .

```
BIDS is a plugin for Visual Studio with additional Project types that are
specific to SQL Server business intelligence.
```

While installing SQL server you should include Integration Service Instance.SSIS runtime is actually not needed to run your packages .
[SSIS Service Usage](http://www.ssistalk.com/2009/11/04/ssis-what-does-the-ssis-service-actually-do-anyway/)

Check out this article

[Description of the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) service and of alternatives to clustering the SSIS service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942176)

`dtexec` utility  comes with SQL Server  to run a SQL Server  Integration Services (SSIS) package .So even without BIDS ,this utility will run your SSIS packages

Comment: I am planning not to install SQL Server DB Engine also, while isntalling if I select only checkbox for Integration Services will I be able to run pacakges through dtexec?

Comment: You need to have server license in order to run DTEXEC utility.So   management studio is essential but Server server DB engine is not needed

Comment: so SSIS Engine + SSMS in production will be enough?

Comment: Yes .To summarize you just need DTEXEC utility to run your package in Production.and that utility gets installed when you pick the "Integration Service Instance" option while installing.Hope that clarifies your doubt

Comment: Is there any Harm in also installing BIDS??

Comment: There is no harm, because you can choose which services gonna run. How you gonna configurate packages on the machine without BIDS? There is already connections and etc?

Comment: There should be some use of installing BIDS in production rit ? Always packages are created in dev and then deployed in prod .Generally these  packages are executed in prod using SQL agent or by C# or VB application.It generally a good practice not to install BIDS in prod as  you don't want any one in production to open your SSIS package using BIDS and mess around with it.

Comment: @Justin : Package Configuration are generally done using Environment variables ,XML file or sql server .So to configure any of these ,you don't need BIDS